# generate a map from an address or longitude and latitude

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have an sql server table "Agency" creates as following:

```
create table Agency (
    Agency_ID int, 
    Agency_Code varchar(20), 
    Agency_Address varchar(100),
    Agency_Name varchar(100),
    Longitude float,
    Latitude float
)
```

I am coding in ColdFusion and I want to generate a maps for each agency using  the longitude and latitude data or the address.

I search a lot on the internet but I did not find a fast way to do it for many thousand row.

Can anyone has an idea about this, or knows an API generating a map easily  using longitude and latitude data?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Did you even try investigating this on your own? Marking to close based on complete lack of effort on your part (and being too broad).

Comment: I agree with Scott - you haven't demonstrated any effort to solve this on your own. You might also clarify whether you want static maps (a map image that show the location with some regional context around it) or interactive maps (pan, zoom, mouse over points for more information in pop-ups, etc.).